# Avoid hardcoding container width

Tags: css, flexbox

I'm setting up a grid of images with flex flow, wrap-reverse. Finally got the container setup to overflow, but I had to artificially increase the size of my box to make it work. How can I remove the `width: 2000px` from the RiddleCharactersTable?

https://codepen.io/matelich/pen/abqjbPm

or a `<ul>` version which doesn't seem to behave any better - https://codepen.io/matelich/pen/rNJrNXe

Comment: Which effect are you going for? Why would you want the items to overflow? You have to artificially set the width because the items aren't big enough to overflow by themselves.

Comment: There may be many items in the table. I want to be able to scroll sideways to reveal them all. With my sample, you should be able to shrink the display until the items wouldn't fit.

Comment: You can get the overflow effect if you change `wrap-reverse` to just `wrap` and remove the `width: 2000px`.. But thats probably not what you want right?

Comment: Correct, Chinese text is right to left, so I'm trying to replicate that. I tried playing with `direction: rtl` but that broke other things.